# Sorted queue with dropping out elements

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have a **list of jobs** and **queue of workers** waiting for these jobs. All the jobs are the same, but workers are different and sorted by their ability to perform the job. That is, first person can do this job best of all, second does it just a little bit worse and so on. Job is always assigned to the **person with the highest skills** from those who are **free** at that moment. When person is assigned a job, he drops out of the queue for some time. But when he is done, he gets back to his position. So, for example, at some moment in time worker queue looks like:

```
[x, x, .83, x, .7, .63, .55, .54, .48, ...]
```

where `x`'s stand for missing workers and numbers show skill level of left workers. When there's a new job, it is assigned to 3rd worker as the one with highest skill of available workers. So next moment queue looks like:

```
[x, x, x, x, .7, .63, .55, .54, .48, ...]
```

Let's say, that at this moment worker #2 finishes his job and gets back to the list:

```
[x, .91, x, x, .7, .63, .55, .54, .48, ...]
```

I hope the process is completely clear now. My question is what **algorithm** and **data structure** to use to implement quick **search and deletion of worker** and **insertion back** to his position.

For the moment the best approach I can see is to use **Fibonacci heap** that have amortized `O(log n)` for deleting minimal element (assigning job and deleting worker from queue) and `O(1)` for inserting him back, which is pretty good. But is there even better algorithm / data structure that possibly take into account the fact that elements are already sorted and only drop of the queue from time to time?

Comment: I think an important consideration when you're actually building something in the real world, is the actual data that will be used. How many workers? How different are there skills? What working patterns will be encountered(eg, highly likely that 3 will always be working, but more than 6 at the same time will almost never happen etc...). You have to be careful of big O because it hides constant factors. If you only have a small amount of workers, the low constant factors involved in linear searching, opposed to a heap will win.

Comment: @rambocoder: Actually, there will be around 1000 workers, and almost all of them will have something to do all the time. So, constant factors are not so important here.

Comment: keep in mind you just stated that whatever data structure you use, will be near empty all the time. you better think hard about those constant factors.

Comment: @rambocoder: that's a good point, thanks!

Comment: @ffriend Constant factors can be extremely important when dealing with small numbers of elements. If you have millions of elements, you can gain by using a more complicated data structure, with high constant factors, because it has low complexity. If k is 10, a method that takes 3k steps beats one that takes 10*log_2(k).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a theoretical exercise, you might consider pre-processing your data to reduce everything to small integers giving position in the full queue. The first thing that springs to mind then is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree, which could in theory reduce log n to log log n. Note that at the end of this article there are some ideas for slightly less impractical solutions. The article off http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.137.8757 (Integer Priority Queues with Decrease Key in constant time...) claims in particular to be theoretically better than Fibonacci trees for the case of small integer keys, and does note the link with the sorting problem - and references another paper with links to sorting - also very theoretical.

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29), which is easier to implement than a Fibonacci heap and also supports insertion and deletions in `O(lg n)` (you have as many deletions as insertions, so getting cheaper insertions isn't worth that much). As opposed to Fibonacci heaps, regular heaps are often implemented in standard libraries, such as `priority_queue` in STL in C++.

If a faster data structure existed, you could use it to perform sorting faster than `Omega(n lg n)`, which is impossible in the general case. If the skill level numbers have some special properties (say, they are integers within a restricted range), it is possible to perform sorting faster than `Omega(n lg n)`, but I don't know whether faster priority queues exist in that case.

("rambo coder"'s comments are absolutely right, by the way; you should compare the actual performance with a heap to that of an unsorted list).